# How to link the data of MongoDB and Neo4j?

Tags: nosql, mongodb, graph-databases

I want to implement a system which store the profiles of employee and the resources that they have. There are many types of resources, such as the documents they produced, the techniques they have...etc.

I store the properties of nodes and relationships on MongoDB, and only store the relationship on Neo4j. But I face a problem, how could I link these two database? For example, when I want to find A's friends who get JAVA license in 2012, I have to find the id of people on MongoDB, and use this id the find the friends on Neo4j, and then I have to check who have JAVA license in 2012 on MongoDB...

I think it is very complex and have some performance issue, how could I solve it? The probable solution I think is storing data both on MongoDB and Neo4j. When I want to do complex search, I can only use Neo4j.

The point of having properties in Mongo is that it has better performance on search by properties, and I think it is better to manage data on MongoDB.

Comment: looks like premature optimization to me. Do you have numbers to back it up? I've the feeling switching from db to db to make your query will be slower than using a single db directly.

Comment: I agree that you should try Neo4j first to verify that it won't meet your needs.  Just make sure you have indexes on the right labels/properties!  If it isn't good enough you should check out this project: https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector